# to find a value in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I got this question in a test few months back , help will be appreciated .

```
result = {
    "Candidate1":{
        "Name": "Eric",
        "Votes": 342
       },
    "Candidate2":{
        "Name": "Max",
        "Votes": 435
        },
    "Candidate3":{
        "Name": "John",
        "Votes": 583
        }
    }
```

I am supposed to Print the name of the person with maximum and votes and also print votes received by him .

Answer (score -1):

If you're allowed to use pandas, I would solve this as follows (N.B. Using transpose to swap the columns/rows around):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(result).transpose()

>>> data
            Name Votes
Candidate1  Eric   342
Candidate2   Max   435
Candidate3  John   583
```

From here just subset the data by the max of the votes column as so:

```
highest_votes = data[data["Votes"] == max(data["Votes"])]
```

Giving:

```
>>> highest_votes
            Name Votes
Candidate3  John   583
```